# nw.js pass element ID to menuitem

Tags: javascript, html, nw.js

I would like to pass element id to the new menuitem through javascript event.

```
<a id="element_1" class="drop-view-link" draggable="false" href="#" oncontextmenu="upShowMenu(event)" onclick="gui.Shell.openExternal(\''+d.url[i].href+'\')">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>

function upShowMenu(e){
e.preventDefault();
menu.popup(e.x, e.y);
//alert(e.target.id);
return false;
}

menu.append(
new gui.MenuItem(
    {
        label: 'Edit',
        click: function(ev){
        //alert(ev.id); ???
        }
    }
)
);
```

Is it possible?
If even possible how can i?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to do something related to clicked (target) element after selecting `Edit`.

Before you pop up context menu, set variable like `contextMenu_element` to target element.

```
var contextMenu_element;

function upShowMenu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    contextMenu_element = e.target;
    menu.popup(e.x, e.y);
    return false;
}
```

Then you can use this variable in click function of menu item:

```
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({
    label: 'Edit',
    click: function() {
        console.log(contextMenu_element.getAttribute('id'));
    }
}));
```

Here we get ID of element by calling `getAttribute('id')`. Every time variable changes, menu item does specific operations on current selected element.

You also can use property of `menu` as variable. Replace `contextMenu_element` to `menu.element`.